# how to run visualforcepage(mobile component) through Mobile

Tags: visualforce, mobile, jquery

I created Mobile App using Visualforce Tag and jquery and also i used apex class functionalities . I dont know how to run the App through Mobile , Kindly give  some suggestions or instructions....

Thanks
S.GaneZ

Answer (score 1):

Expose your visualforce as visualforce tab and make it mobile ready and Mark in visualforce as Available for mobile and use in salesforce 1 app or create a publisher action for your on record detail to navigate to your page .

[image]

I will personally prefer approach one to expose as visualforce tab

Update:

> **Add this visualforce page to the mobile navigation menu .Please note only once you make a tab as mobile ready and also make the page as available for salesforce 1 ,you wont be able to see in navigation menu**

In your browser type sfdc url followed by one/one.app and then click on pin to access this .Note this wont need you any mobile app you can test on browser itself .

Comment: Thanks for u reply@mohith , i wont use salesforce1 , can you give any other suggestion

Comment: update the answer .Hope that helps you to test your page